# python 3 list homework has me stumped

Tags: list, function, python-3.x

okay, so I'm supposed to create a wizard inventory program that lists the items the wizard currently has on him. At most, he can hold 4 items, and starts with 3. My functions seem to be the issue, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong from the book.

My show function works like a charm...my edit isn't editing...and yeah. I'll just post this up, and hopefully you guys can clue me in on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for all the help in advance. (No, I'm not asking anyone to do my homework...but maybe just point me in the right direction)

```
print ("The Wizard Inventory program")

inventory = ["orb", "staff", "spellbook"]

def opening_menu():
    print("Command Menu")
    print("show - Show all items")
    print("grab - Grab an item")
    print("edit - Edit an item")
    print("drop - Drop an item")
    print("exit - Exit program")
    print()

def show_it():
    inventory = ["orb", "staff", "spellbook"]
    for item in inventory:
        print(item)

def grab_it():
    print("which item would you like to add??" )
    if (item -1) in range (master_inventory_list):
        while yes:
            grab_it (inventory, " ")

def edit_it():
    inventory = ["orb", "staff", "spellbook", "hat", "potion", "robe"]
    item = input("What item are you looking for? ")
    if item in inventory:
        inventory.remove(item)

def drop_it():
    inventory = ["orb", "staff", "spellbook", "hat", "potion", "robe"]
    item = input("What item would you like to drop? ")
    for item in inventory:
        inventory.pop()

def exit_it():
    choice = y
    while choice.lower() == "y":
        print("Do you want to stay inside your inventory? (y/n): ")
        print()
        print("Goodbye!!")

def master_inventory_list():
    master_inventory_list = ["orb", "staff", "spellbook", "hat", "potion", "robe"]

opening_menu()

while True:
    command = input("Command: ")
    if command.lower() == "show":
        show_it()
    elif command.lower() == "grab":
        grab_it()
    elif command.lower() == "edit":
        edit_it()
    elif command.lower() == "drop":
        drop_it()
    elif command.lower() == "exit":
        break
    else:
        print("Not a valid choice! Please choose again. \n")


print("Goodbye!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You said homework, so I'll assume you've just started learning in the past month or so.

Just taking a glance at it, perhaps it's the lack of return statements / global inventories / whatever reflects your changes in inventory?

> def edit_it():
>       inventory = ["orb", "staff", "spellbook", "hat", "potion", "robe"]
>       item = input("What item are you looking for? ")
>       if item in inventory:
>           inventory.remove(item)

In a function (like edit_it), all your variables are either arguments to the function, created within the function, or global variables. If you want your inventory to reflect your changes, you need to output it in a return statement. A return statement will give you your list / inventory, but it's up to you to take the list. You can assign the value of the returned list to another variable.

However, because you define inventory inside the function, every time you call the function, you will do this declaration / assignment:

> inventory = ["orb", "staff", "spellbook", "hat", "potion", "robe"]

Effectively, you would never get past 5 items. So in addition to a return function, you probably want to pass the inventory to your edit_it function as an argument every time you want to, well, edit it. So as an example:

```
def example(inventory, itemToRemove):
    inventory.remove(itemToRemove)
    return inventory

newThing = example(oldThing, theUserInput)

newerThing = example(newThing, theNewUserInput)
```

(These are terrible function names, by the way, but I think it gives a decent summary of the general structure I'm getting at. There's stuff to be said about efficiency and clarity, but meh.)

Additionally, if you don't mind me asking, why do you have master_inventory_list() as it is? If it's meant to be a value that you can use throughout your program, there's a better way (and it's not really how functions are to be used).

Comment: the master inventory list is really for me I guess? I wanted something to list that would show the maximum amount of items possible. Yes, I did just start learning this stuff rather recently.

Comment: Thanks for the comment by the way! I haven't had a chance to read the full post yet (life obligations in the morning) but after skimming it, your suggestions will help!! So thanks for that. :)

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha. Yeah, the way you have master_inventory_list in the function,  it seemed like it was being used as a normal variable. Nothing bad would really happen, but also nothing would happen in general. So if your instructor takes off points for (what seems like) minor reasons, the way that function is now, it would probably qualify.

Comment: And no problem! I hope it helps you out, and feel free to ask if you need clarification. Python is a really fun, rewarding way to learn programming.

Comment: do you think you can show me another example for edit, or for drop/add? I keep getting traceback errors and I don't know why....

def edit_it(inventory):
    item = input("What item are you looking for? ")
    if item in inventory:
        inventory.remove(item)
        return inventory

Comment: and yeah, I like the class...just the professor doesn't do enough examples... I'm visual and hands on...so it's making it rather difficult for me.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\infer\OneDrive\Documents\School Classes\Programming Logic (COP2002)\Homework\My Homework Programs\wizard_inventory_martinez.py", line 53, in <module>
    grab_it()
  File "C:\Users\infer\OneDrive\Documents\School Classes\Programming Logic (COP2002)\Homework\My Homework Programs\wizard_inventory_martinez.py", line 22, in grab_it
    if (item -1) in range (inventory):
NameError: name 'item' is not defined
>>>

Comment: Sure, although in the spirit of "we're stackoverflow and we don't do your homework!" I'll be a little light on this answer.

1) So you gave me edit_it, presumably because since you just changed it, you figured any issues in your program had to do with edit_it. This is possible, but another common scenario is that now that edit_it is correct, the compiler continues and runs into errors further down your program.

Comment: If you take a look at your error message-- always look for the words that say "line." The first line it prints isn't necessarily your issue, because functions can use other functions, so it gives you multiple lines for the same error. It mentions line 53, and from what I can tell there's nothing there. It then mentions line 22, so that's generally where the compiler is having issues.

Comment: 2) "def" indicates a function definition. The word following tells us the function name (grab_it) and the parenthesis following holds the "arguments" the function takes. A function doesn't need arguments to be a function, BUT if you want to give it arguments later (grab_it (inventory, " ")), you have to give it arguments in the line that says "def" where your parentheses are currently empty.

Comment: 3) So what kind of arguments do you put in a definition? For Python (this isn't true in a lot of languages), all you have to do is give your arguments some place-holder names. The inside of a function is sort of like it's own little world, and in the function definition, the arguments you put inside the parentheses only exist inside the function for which it is an argument. (Unless it's global, I think, but globals are bad practice)

Comment: As an example:

def thisFunction(randomName1, randomName2):
    print(randomName1, randomName2)

print(randomName1)

If we tried to print randomName1 outside that function, it would give us an error because it's not defined. Python doesn't know what that variable could be or what to print.

Now, let's give randomName1 a value and call the function.

randomName1 = 2

thisFunction()

This would also give us an error, because we need to pass values to thisFunction and we haven't. It doesn't matter if the variable we defined shares a name with a variable in the definition.

Comment: (Dang Stack, what's with your lack of formatting for comments?)

Comment: 4) So we've figured out the idea of scope-- the idea that some variables only exist in one part of the program and not others. But how do we apply this to grab_it? What does grab_it need?

Comment: 5) For grab_it's definition, you can give its arguments any name. Really. it could be def grab_it(darnYou, professor) and python would be fine with it as long as you use those variables consistently. For readability's sake, most people give their variables intuitive names. So let's go with grab_it(inventory, item).

Comment: 6) But, your function still might not work. Python guesses the type of variable you're using, but once it makes a guess, it will hold you to it wherever the variable exists. In the body of your function, you write:
 if (item -1) in range (master_inventory_list). What Python does when it sees this line is, it assumes item is an integer (because you're trying to subtract from it). I need to brush up on what, exactly, range does to a list of strings, but the point is that python is looking for an integer.

Comment: Also, Python doesn't even know what master_inventory_list is, because it's neither global nor has it been passed as an argument to your function. But if you want to check whether someone asked for something in the inventory, all you have to do is type. "if item in inventory." It goes through all of inventory for you.

Comment: You're also doing a while loop (which are super slow in python btw) and I'm not exactly sure what you're getting at with it. (I also don't think "yes" is understood by python to mean anything). If you want to check that something is in the inventory list before you "grab_it" you can't write it as you did. What happens is that python hears "if the item is in the inventory, call the function again." It's a recursive function at that point, because if the item is always in the inventory, it calls itself and then asks again whether or not the item is in the inventory and then calls itself and etc.

Comment: This is doubly so because it's in a while loop without a real terminating condition. Even if your function didn't call itself, you need to structure your while loop so that it ends when you want it to end.

Comment: So this got really long, but if I had to change it:

def grab_it(): #add arguments
    print("which item would you like to add??" ) #use input() to catch answer
    if (item -1) in range (master_inventory_list): #remove range and make item an argument
        while yes: #no whileloops
            grab_it (inventory, " ") #take another argument to be your inventory and add to this inventory what the user input
#probably have an "else" statement, but I don't know what your program is like so you do you

Comment: Hope that helps for the program in general!! If you're ever confused, look up what a function needs or does: https://docs.python.org/3.6/ . it can be daunting, but it's very informative.

Comment: (also http://python-course.eu if you have basic questions and want a lot of examples!)

Comment: I haven't read any of this yet...but you're my freaking hero. Just an fyi.